# JavaFX, открытие нового окна при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: java, javafx, gui

Пишу на скорую руку приложение на JavaFX, инициализировал главное с кнопками, но не понимаю, как инициализировать кнопку в контроллере, чтобы при нажатии на нее открывалось новое окно (старое не закрывалось) с другой сценой, которая загружается из другого fxml файла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это окно, которое будет открываться( отдельный fxml)

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(StartGraphicsHere.class.getResource("/fxml/ApEditDialog.fxml"));
AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
dialogStage.setTitle("Edit Profile");
dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
dialogStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
Scene scene = new Scene(page);
dialogStage.setScene(scene);
```

Comment: не особо понятно, на самом деле. у вас есть контроллер, в котором есть что-то такое: @FXML
    protected void onCreateButtonClick() throws IOException {
        createTable.setText("Создаём таблицу..");
          }
при нажатии на кнопку onCreateButtonClick я хочу запустить новое окно. как это сделать - не понятно. Стейджа то нет. а если его прописать как Stage stage = new Stage(); то всё просто упадёт моментально.